# Bonfire Unread Count: Add the unread messages count to the favicon

Tags: script, chat, extension

#### About:

I wanted to be able to pin the chat rooms I'm on, but I wouldn't know how many unread messages there were.

With this extension, I can pin the tab.

#### Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

#### Download / Install:

- You can find it on the stores for [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bonfire-unread-count/mjnidngiefjlkmkmjllnpbailmgecphn) or [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/bonfire-unread-count/)
- You can download [its source code](https://github.com/g3rv4/BonfireUnread) and load it unpacked

#### Platform:

Tested on Chrome, Firefox and Opera

#### Contact:

Create an issue on GitHub :)

#### License:

It's [MIT licensed](https://github.com/g3rv4/BonfireUnread/blob/master/LICENSE).